# What is the file path of the default Windows notification area icons?

Tags: windows, icons, notification-area

I'm designing an icon. I want to copy the style of the default notification area icons in Windows: Volume, Network, Action Center, Battery, etc.

[image: screen shot of notification area and volume slider]

What is the file path of the default Windows notification area icons? I assume they're in a DLL or EXE somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the DLLs you can check out:

```
Windows\System32\ActionCenter.dll
Windows\system32\batt.dll
Windows\System32\pnidui.dll
Windows\System32\SndVolSSO.dll
```

Also:

```
Windows\System32\ActionCenterCPL.dll
Windows\System32\imageres.dll
Windows\System32\Shell32.dll
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should find some of them here.

%windir%\system32\compstui.dll (Com­mon Prop­erty Sheet User Interface)

%windir%\system32\ddores.dll (Device Cat­egory Inform­a­tion and Resources)

%windir%\system32\ieframe.dll (Inter­net Explorer)

%windir%\system32\imageres.dll (Win­dows Image Resource)

%windir%\system32\netshell.dll (Net­work Con­nec­tions Shell)

%windir%\system32\pnidui.dll (Net­work Sys­tem Icons)

%windir%\system32\shell32.dll (Win­dows Shell Common)

%windir%\system32\wpdshext.dll (Port­able Devices Shell Extension)

%windir%\system32\mmcndmgr.dll (Microsoft Man­age­ment Con­sole Node Manager)

Comment: Note: ddores.dll has several of the icons seen in the "Playback devices" and "Recording devices" menus.